# SQL query not equal to 0.00

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I am trying to query a database with something like:

```
select q.column1, q.column2 
from table q
where q.column1 <> 0.00
```

but the results are returning 0.00. The column contains numeric values. I have tried 'is not', <>, and != but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Could it be a rounding issue?

Comment: What data type is `column1` of?

Comment: Could you just put `0` instead of '0.00'?

Comment: `select q.column1, q.column2 
from table q
where ROUND(q.column1,2) <> 0.00` Test if its rounding issue as @MikyDinescu suggested

Comment: It is a numeric data type

Comment: Please show table structures and sample data to populate the table and show the results of the select.

Answer (score 1):

Does `column1` have an [approximate numeric data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)?  Like `float` or `real`.

If so, those data types are not exact.  You should avoid the equality `=` operator when dealing with approximate numbers.

A better approach is to check if the approximate number is close to the number you're looking for.  You can use `abs([TargetValue] - [YourColumn]) < [SmallNumber]` for that:

```
where abs(0 - q.column1) < 0.0001
```

An example of how it goes wrong:

```
create table t1 (descr varchar(max), nr float);
insert t1 values 
    ('1E-307', 1E-307),
    ('1E-308', 1E-308),
    ('0', 0);

select * from t1 where nr = 0
```

This prints

```
descr    nr
1E-308   0
0        0
```

The row with `1E-307` is missing, but the row with `1E-308` is present :)

Comment: Column1 is (numeric(10,2), null)
I do not know if it is an approximate numeric data type. How could I find this out?

Comment: `numeric` is an exact data type.  Can you reproduce the problem at http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.column1, A.column2 
FROM (SELECT CAST(q.column1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS column1 ,
             CAST(q.column2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS column2 
      FROM [table] q) A
WHERE A.column1 <> 0.00
```

Comment: Thank you. I used and the CAST and was able to get better results although this did not eliminate all the 0.00.